# Python: How to reshape an array based on image input?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning

I have a function which applies masking operation on the input images as follows:

```
file_names = glob(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, "*.jpg"))
masks_prediction = np.zeros((2000, 2000, len(file_names)))
for i in range(len(file_names)):
    print(i)
    image = skimage.io.imread(file_names[i])
    predictions = model.detect([image],  verbose=1)
    p = predictions[0]
    masks = p['masks']
    merged_mask = np.zeros((masks.shape[0], masks.shape[1]))
    for j in range(masks.shape[2]):
        merged_mask[masks[:,:,j]==True] = True
        masks_prediction[:,:,i] = merged_mask
print(masks_prediction.shape)
```

So basically it reads all the images from the directory, creates a mask for each and runs the detection.

However, since the images are of different sizes, it does not work:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-764e6229811a> in <module>()
     10     for j in range(masks.shape[2]):
     11         merged_mask[masks[:,:,j]==True] = True
---> 12         masks_prediction[:,:,i] = merged_mask
     13 print(masks_prediction.shape)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1518,1077) into shape (2000,2000)
```

I was thinking of a way to know the size of each image before the mask operation is applied (before line 12 in the error message), thus passing the exact image shape size correctly for the masking operation.

Is this somehow possible in Python?

**EDIT:** So apparently people somehow didn't get what I wanted to achieve - although I genuinely believe it was written in a very simple way. Nevertheless here is the entire code (copied from ipython notebook) where the function is located:

```
import os
import sys
import random
import math
import re
import time
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import skimage.draw

# Root directory of the project
ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath("../../")

# Import Mask RCNN
sys.path.append(ROOT_DIR)  # To find local version of the library
from mrcnn import utils
from mrcnn import visualize
from mrcnn.visualize import display_images
import mrcnn.model as modellib
from mrcnn.model import log
from glob import glob


import components

%matplotlib inline 

# Directories to be referred
MODEL_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "logs")
IMAGE_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "datasets/components/back/predict")
ANNOTATION_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "datasets/components/front/")
WEIGHTS_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "logs/back/mask_rcnn_components_0100.h5")

config = components.ComponentsConfig()
# Override the training configurations with a few
# changes for inferencing.
class InferenceConfig(config.__class__):
# Run detection on one image at a time
GPU_COUNT = 1
IMAGES_PER_GPU = 1

 config = InferenceConfig()
 config.display()
 # Create model in inference mode
with tf.device(DEVICE):
    model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir=MODEL_DIR,
                              config=config)
# Load weights
print("Loading weights ", WEIGHTS_PATH)
model.load_weights(WEIGHTS_PATH, by_name=True)

file_names = glob(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, "*.jpg"))
masks_prediction = np.zeros((2000, 2000, len(file_names)))
for i in range(len(file_names)):
    print(i)
    image = skimage.io.imread(file_names[i])
    predictions = model.detect([image],  verbose=1)
    p = predictions[0]
    masks = p['masks']
    merged_mask = np.zeros((masks.shape[0], masks.shape[1]))
    for j in range(masks.shape[2]):
        merged_mask[masks[:,:,j]==True] = True
        masks_prediction[:,:,i] = merged_mask
print(masks_prediction.shape)

dataset = components.ComponentsDataset()
dataset.load_components(ANNOTATION_DIR, "predict")

accuracy = 0
precision = 0
for image_id in range(len(dataset.image_info)):
    name = dataset.image_info[image_id]['id']
    file_name = os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, name)
    image_id_pred = file_names.index(file_name)
    merged_mask = masks_prediction[:, :, image_id_pred]

    annotated_mask = dataset.load_mask(image_id)[0]
    merged_annotated_mask = np.zeros((510, 510))
    for i in range(annotated_mask.shape[2]):
        merged_annotated_mask[annotated_mask[:,:,i]==True] = True
    accuracy  += np.sum(merged_mask==merged_annotated_mask) / (1200 * 1600)
    all_correct = np.sum(merged_annotated_mask[merged_mask == 1])
    precision += all_correct / (np.sum(merged_mask))
print('accuracy:{}'.format(accuracy / len(file_names)))
print('precision:{}'.format(precision / len(file_names)))

file_names = glob(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, "*.jpg"))
class_names = ['BG', 'screw', 'lid']
test_image = skimage.io.imread(file_names[random.randint(0,len(file_names)-1)])
predictions = model.detect([test_image], verbose=1) # We are replicating the same image to fill up the batch_size
p = predictions[0]
visualize.display_instances(test_image, p['rois'], p['masks'], p['class_ids'], 
                            class_names, p['scores'])
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and clarify your question.  As it is now it's not clear what you want to do, or what's actually happening.  A big part of the problem is your code can't be run be someone else in its current state, so everything after `model.detect` is completely opaque to us.

Comment: I did explain what I want to do in the question. I cannot post the entire code here, wouldn't make sense and no one would be able to run it anyway.

Comment: A complete example is NOT posting all your code.  No one here wants to see your code.  What we want to see is just enough code to cause the same trouble that you're seeing without having to understand the labyrinthine intricacies of your code.

Comment: Can you pad your images so that they're all of size `(2000, 2000)`? Otherwise, I don't see how you can have a 3-dimensional matrix where the first two dimensions aren't fixed

Comment: I'm sure it's clear *to you* what you want to do, but without a [mcve], it's not clear to us.  The best we can do without a good grounding of the inputs, outputs and processes involved, is point you in general directions like @marco_gorelli above.  We can't help you implement it (which is the point of SO) because we have no context to implement within.

Comment: @marco_gorelli There are vision libraries which provide functionality of image resizing. I do know they exist for C++, I just don't know what's there for Python.

Comment: @user2699 What I posted is the entire function. What else should I post? I really don't get all the "This is incomplete" fuss. I mean, the hell, I am just going to post the entire code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is just a numpy array. So to answer your question "is it possible to know the size of each image": Yes, simply use the `shape` of the image.

If you are working on many images of different sizes, it might make sense to resize them to a uniform resolution.
`skimage` has a built-in functionality for that, the `skimage.transform.resize` method.
Look at the docs [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.resize).

If you use resize, you should make sure that no artifacts are introduced to your images. Check the result of the resizing operation before you use it.

The resize of `skimage` is fairly slow. If you need more performance, you could use opencv. They have a great python API and since there is a [conda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv) package, installation has become really easy.

```
resized_images = []
file_names = glob(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, "*.jpg")) 
for i in range(len(file_names)):
    print("Resizing: " + str(i))
    image = skimage.io.imread(file_names[i])
    image_resized = resize(image, (1200, 800),anti_aliasing=True)
    resized_images.append(image_resized)
```